# How to avoid blank page for a Microsoft Graph API consent opened from an Outlook web addin onboarding

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am coding a consent flow in an Outlook Web add-in. I used the `displayDialogAsync` method, which opens on the same domain (declared in the manifest), a redirect page.

Everything works on the web, but when launched from Outlook desktop, a blank/empty page is rendered.

If I remove the `s` from the `https redirect_uri`, the redirection works and the consent screen appears, but this isn't a final solution since the `https` redirection URI is mandatory. It just means the URL is wellformed, and the redirection is theoretically working.

I followed the step-by-step [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#use-the-dialog-apis-in-an-authentication-flow) and the domain of the redirect URI is declared in the add-in's manifest.

Code I'm using (`getParametersByName` just extracts the URL parameters to rebuild the consent URL)

```
var redirect_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize\
    ?response_type=code\
    &redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_mode=query&domain_hint=organizations\
    &scope=' + getParameterByName('scope') + 
    '&client_id=' + getParameterByName('client_id') +
    '&login_hint=' + getParameterByName('login_hint') + 
    '&state=' + getParameterByName('state');

window.location.href = redirect_uri;
```

What is blocking/filtering this redirect_uri parameter?

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using? Are you seeing any errors when the empty page is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The single most important thing to understand about building Web Add-ins for Office is that you're writing for Internet Explorer 11. The reason for this is that Office for Windows is backward compatible to Windows 7 and, as such, it cannot embed Microsoft Edge (which isn't available on 7).

The reason you're running into this issue is that string continuation (`\`) wasn't introduced until ECMAScript 2015 (aka 6.0) while IE11 only supports up to ECMAScript 5.1.

This string should solve your problem:

```
var redirect_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize' +
    '?response_type=code' +
    '&redirect_uri={redirect_uri on the same domain}' +
    '&response_mode=query' + 
    '&domain_hint=organizations' +
    '&scope=' + getParameterByName('scope') + 
    '&client_id=' + getParameterByName('client_id') + 
    '&login_hint=' + getParameterByName('login_hint') + 
    '&state=' + getParameterByName('state');

window.location.href = redirect_uri;
```